# Intellij, add @Author or file header on a set of files

Tags: intellij-idea

I already have lots of code written and I would like to add my custom:

```
/**
 * @Author 
**/
```

tag on all java classes.

Intellij adds this when I create new classes but how can I add it if the files are already created?

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in way to add Javadoc to any class that is missing it. And definitely not a way to (directly) say add the `@Author` tag to any Javadoc missing it.

The ideal way to do what you want would be to use the Structural Search and Replace feature (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> or *Edit Search > Replace Structurally*) With it, you could run a search & replace to add Javadoc to any class missing it, and then one to add the `@Author` tag to any class with Javadoc but without the `@Author` tag.

Take a look at the IntelliJ IDEA help on Structural search and replace. You can also take a look at [Structural Search and Replace: What, Why, and How-to](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/ssr.html) and [Basics of working with structural search](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Basics_of_working_with_structural_search).

Comment: Example is broken. Any insights ?